# Keep Tweepy script from replying the same mentions

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm  making a bot with Python and Tweepy that answers with a image when mentioned, but he keeping replying the same tweets. I tried to use a If to counter that, but isn't working.

```
import tweepy
import os
import time
import random

os.chdir ('images')

#Keys to API

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret =''

#Auth to API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)    
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.me()
print (user.name)

def reply_bot():
    search = api.search(q='@KancolleSleep')
    for tweet in search:
        print (f'UserName: {tweet.user.screen_name}')
        name = tweet.user.screen_name
        message = []
        message += (tweet.text)
        message2 = (tweet.text)
        if message2 != message:
            print (f'Tweet: {tweet.text}')
            media_ids = []
            image1 = random.choice(os.listdir('.'))
            file = api.media_upload(image1)
            media_ids.append(file.media_id)
            print (image1)
            text = (f'@{name}')
            api.update_status(status=text, media_ids=media_ids, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
        else:
            print ("Tweet already answered")

while True:
    reply_bot()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Theres a effective way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I'm assuming every tweet has an id. Can't you just store a list of the ids of tweets the bot has replied to and, for every new tweet, check if it is already in the list?

Comment: This is probably too broad IMO.

Comment: You could get the contents of the tweet, author, date of writing etc then hash it and save it in a database if you can't get some sort of tweet id

Comment: @StanvanRooy solution worked! Thank you guys for the helping! o/

Comment: @StanvanRooy I’m confused, had I said something about the solution or scaling before?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile nevermind, I misunderstood your comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming every tweet has an id. You can just store a list of the ids of tweets the bot has replied to and, for every new tweet, check if it is already in the list.

Here's an example:

```py
already_answered = []
def reply_bot():
    search = api.search(q='@KancolleSleep')
    for tweet in search:
        # add your code
        if tweet.id not in already_answered:
            # add your code
            already_answered.append(tweet.id)
        else:
            print('tweet already answered')
```